# How to use variables in arcpy tools which quote the variable name

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst

I'm having a frustrating time trying to use the Create TIN tool within Python, when the input featureclass name is a variable.

The help file entry for [Create TIN](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000001v000000) shows a hard-coded path to the featureclass "points.shp" in the stand-alone example:

```
arcpy.CreateTin_3d("NewTIN", "....prj", "points.shp Shape.Z masspoints")
```

The script example uses {0}:

```
arcpy.ddd.CreateTin(outTin, sr, "{0} Shape.Z masspoints" .format(lasMP), "Delaunay")
```

It's unclear to me what the {0} represents (the first argument? - what if I don't have an argument, but only have access to a variable?).

The syntax section of the help file shows that the in_features can be specified as an array (of arrays?):

```
[[in_feature_class, height_field, SF_type, tag_value],...]
```

but I can't get this to work - it returns a generic "ERROR 999999: Error executing function".

So my question is, how can I use a variable as the featureclass name in the CreateTIN tool within Python?

Here is my non-functioning code:

```
fc = "path_to_featureClass"
tin = "path_to_output_TIN"
sr = "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]"

arcpy.CreateTin_3d(tin, sr, [fc + "fieldName Hard_Line <None>"], "DELAUNAY")
```

(where I have valid paths to **fc** and **tin**, and **fieldName** is a valid field on the layer.) I can successfully create a TIN using this dataset when using the tool manually.

Comment: Have you tried running it manually and then using **Copy As Python Snippet** to snag the syntax from the **Geoprocessing | Results** window.

Comment: @PolyGeo I tried exporting from a model - this sets a variable for the FC, but ignores this and uses the full FC path in the CreateTIN line anyway...

Comment: As mentioned by @blah238 earlier today in answer to another question, the export from model to Python/ArcPy is quite flawed http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/24/exportmodeltopy/  I suspect Copy As Python Snippet may do a better job but have not tested your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks almost like mine but I don't use brackets for the Value Table and use {}.format for variable substitution:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
fc = r"C:/GIS/Temp/test.gdb/Points3D"
tin = r"C:/Users/user/Documents/ArcGIS/CreateTin5"
sr = "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]"
in_field = "ELEVATION"

arcpy.CreateTin_3d(tin,sr,"{0} {1} Mass_Points <None>".format(fc,in_field),"DELAUNAY")
```

{0} and {1} is a way to substitute the values with variables and you can use .format to specify the variables according to the index number -- sequence.

Comment: thanks, this looks like what I need to do. Is that variable substitution method documented anywhere? It is an arcpy thing, or a python thing?

Comment: @StephenLead, it is a Python thing. There are multiple ways to include variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451989/pythons-many-ways-of-string-formatting-are-the-older-ones-going-to-be-deprec (really good ones to read!). I prefer using .format, but as you can read from those threads others are used, too.